# Using gamepad-api via events, rather than polling

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gamepad, gamepad-api

I am building a chrome extension that would enable the use of my 3d-mouse (made by 3d connexion) to scroll web pages. The built-in 3d connexion drivers are worthless, and the 3d mouse presents itself as a 2 button, 6 axis gamepad to the OS.

The implementation is currently working using the below method:

```
function get3DMouseData() {
    if (document.hasFocus()) {
        var gp = navigator.getGamepads()[0]
        // axis 5 controls scroll speed
        if (gp.axes[5]) window.scrollBy(0,Math.round(gp.axes[5]*10)*10)
    }
}

interval = this.setInterval(get3DMouseData, 50)
```

It doesn't seem to be the smartest strategy to run `get3DMouseData` 20 times por second, and an event-based implementation would probably be more efficient.

1. Is there an event-based methods for the gamepad-api that I can use in the case above?
2. This implementation does not work properly in certain sites (like gmail). What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such events:

> Other events:
> More discussion needed, on whether to include or exclude axis and
> button changed events, and whether to roll them more together
> ("gamepadchanged"?), separate somewhat ("gamepadaxischanged"?), or
> separate by individual axis and button.

Also it is said that proper polling is a best practice:

> Best Practice 1: Coordination with requestAnimationFrame() Interactive
> applications will typically be using the requestAnimationFrame()
> method to drive animation, and will want coordinate animation with
> user gamepad input. As such, the gamepad data should be polled as
> closely as possible to immediately before the animation callbacks are
> executed, and with frequency matching that of the animation. That is,
> if the animation callbacks are running at 60Hz, the gamepad inputs
> should also be sampled at that rate.

Regarding gmail: I guess that it is due restriction policy set on that site:

> This specification defines a policy-controlled feature identified by
> the string "gamepad". Its default allowlist is 'self'.

> 'self'
> The feature is allowed in documents in top-level browsing contexts by default, and when allowed, is allowed by default to same-origin domain documents in child browsing contexts, but is disallowed by default in cross-origin documents in child browsing contexts.

https://www.w3.org/TR/gamepad/

Comment: Many thanks. Will work with them to implement this

Comment: There is a 7-year long discussion on the topic, available here: https://github.com/w3c/gamepad/issues/4

Comment: And this explainer: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1At2ZsMOow4LmIhLs_LfnUV8J9glJS8qSyW-PqYtrQVA/edit